# Spring exception while deploying war on Oracle 12 C

Tags: java, spring, dwr

I am deploying my application on Oracle 12 C. But I am getting below exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate NamespaceHandler for namespace [http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

Here is content of applicationcontext.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
       http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
       http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd">
```

Same configuration is working on Oracle 10.3 but giving exception in 12 C. Please help.

Comment: Do you have the spring integration jar's in your classpath? Try to remove the version nuber from the xsd name.

Comment: The `dwr.jar` is missing i think. Version 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have dwr jar in you classpath. I guess it's only the jar issue as config looks fine.

Comment: Yes..I have already placed dwr jar file in WEB-INF/lib folder.But issue is still there.

Comment: ok then after http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr isee an enter used instead of space. Can you replace enter with space between http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr  and http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd">

Comment: Still i am facing same issue.

Comment: Then it might be a class loading issue. I have limited knowledge on weblogic but you can refer http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/03/weblogic-classloader-analysis-tool.html to see if dwr classes are being loaded. May be you can try by removing dwr.jar from lib or explode the jar to see if there is some entry in META-INF files